# Please explain the method from Integer class

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation

I am new to bit shifting and want to know when to use this shifting ? The method below converts an integer to binary,octal and hexadecimal where "shift" would be 2,3 or 4 and i be any integer.

```
private static String toUnsignedString(int i, int shift) {
   char[] buf = new char[32];
   int charPos = 32;
   int radix = 1 << shift;
   int mask = radix - 1;
   do {
      buf[--charPos] = digits[i & mask];
      i >>>= shift;
   } while (i != 0);

   return new String(buf, charPos, (32 - charPos));
}
```

where

```
final static char[] digits = {
   '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
   '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
   'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
   'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
   'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
   'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
};
```

I am not able to understand this method . Please explain.

Comment: This absolutely does not answer your question but this link might be useful to you : http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Did you try stepping through the method (either by hand or with a debugger)? What part don't you understand?

Comment: (Shifting right == division, shifting left == multiplication) by 2 ^ number of bits shifted.  That may help you understand what is actually going on.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for your comment. I am not getting the logic behind the masking and bit shifting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think that your description of the arguments is wrong. This will generate binary when the argument `shift` is 1, not 2.

The way it works is that the method first calculates `mask` to be an `int` value that is all zero except for the bottom (least significant) `shift` bits are 1. The loop then repeatedly looks up the digit corresponding to the least significant `shift` bits of `i` and then shifts `i` to the right by `shift` bits. (The `>>>=` assignment shifts to the right and fills with zero on the left. If the method had incorrectly used the `>>=` assignment, it would fill with the sign bit.) The loop stops when `i` reaches 0. By using a `do...while` loop instead of a `while` loop, the method always generates some output, even if `i` starts as 0.

Perhaps the trickiest part is realizing that the way `mask` is computed results in exactly the bottom `shift` bits of `mask` being set to 1. The expression `1 << shift` has the value of 2<sup>`shift`</sup>, so `mask` gets the value 2<sup>`shift`</sup> - 1, which is always `shift` bits of 1.

```
1 << shift:
   000000...000010  .  .  .  0
                 |<- shift ->|
                     bits
                     all 0
(1 << shift) - 1:
   000000...000001  .  .  .  1
                 |<- shift ->|
                     bits
                     all 1
```

Here's a simple example with arguments 47 and 3:

> `radix` is set to 8 (`1 << 3`)
>   `mask` is set to 7 (111 in binary)
>   `i` starts with binary value of 101111
>   `charPos` is set to 32
>   First loop iteration:
>       `i & mask` is bit pattern 111, which is 7;
>       `charPos` is decremented to 31
>       `buf[31]` is set to the character '7'
>       `i` is set to `i >>> 3`, or binary 101
>   Second loop iteration:
>       `i & mask` is 101, which is 5;
>       `charPos` is decremented to 30
>       `buf[30]` is set to the character '5'
>       `i` is set to `i >>> 3`, which is 0; the loop ends
>   The method returns the `String` formed by the (32 - charPos =) 2 characters at `buf[30]` and `buf[31]`.

Result: the octal representation of 47 is 57.

Comment: Maybe add why that masking trick works ( 1 << n ) - 1 --> number with all 1's in n-1 lsb's

Comment: @fvu - Done, along with a simulation of a typical call that perhaps helps with that.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for the valuable explanation. This explains how this method works.clear. but why we use the lsb to mask with the no. bits so that it matches the array index ?

Comment: @user1682878 because this kind of masking behaves like the modulo operator - `number & ( 1 << n ) - 1` == `number % ( 1 << n )` ie the result will always satisfy `0 <= result <= ( 1 << n ) - 1`

Comment: @user1682878 - and-ing with the lsb mask generates a value between 0 and (2^shift)-1; this then can serve nicely as an index into the `digits` array. Because the loop generates digits starting with the least significant position, the `buf` array needs to be filled from the right, which is why `charPos` starts at 32 and goes down.

Comment: @TedHopp what if we do not use & with lsb's the result would be the same ?

Comment: @user1682878 - If you did not `&` with lsb, the first iteration would try to look up `digits[47]`, which would generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.